# Is dysharmonia an actual disease or something only Oliver Sacks believes in?

Tags: brain

In his book *Musicophilia*, Oliver Sacks discusses a case involving a woman named Rachel Y. who lost the ability to process harmony in a car accident. He then explains how this lead to [simultanagnosia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultanagnosia). He terms this loss of harmony "dysharmonia."

Is dysharmonia an actual medical condition or is this something Sacks just believes but has no real evidence for? My google fu didn't yield anything besides his book.  If it is legit, which regions of the brain are damaged and why are those regions in particular thought to induce dysharmonia?

Click [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=wuyZiwgsBdoC&pg=PA121&lpg=PA121&dq=rachel+y+dysharmonia&source=bl&ots=hgU-zOVDhu&sig=lh4WxvwwkV2eAgtSh73aqfp6OIY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAGoVChMI-r-vjYyfxwIVRBU-Ch0Oogqt#v=onepage&q=rachel%20y%20dysharmonia&f=false) to read the case.

Comment: This *might* be better suited to [skeptics.se], I'm not sure...

Comment: Never used Skeptics so I can't really say if I agree or disagree. If it is, that's fine. I'll let others weigh in and if it is mods can migrate it.

Comment: Check out their [welcome to new users](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/faq-welcome-to-new-users) post to learn about the site and how it works. You don't necessarily need to have the mods migrate it, you could just post the question there, possibly with some edits to satisfy their question criteria.